# Using ST_Intersect in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I am a beginner with PostGIS.

I would like to know if it’s possible to use Count or “>” with `ST_Intersect`.

Which districts sit in 3 neighbourhoods ?

```
SELECT district.name
FROM district 
JOIN quartier ON district.quartier= quartier.district
WHERE count (ST_Intersects (district.geom, quartier.geom))
```

Comment: The SQL language doesn't change with the addition of spatial operators. Your SQL construct is not valid -- a count of Booleans doesn't make a logical expression. Your table and column naming is very confusing. Please [Edit] the question to better describe what data you have and how the tables are related, and what you are trying to obtain.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
With this request Select district.nom,count (quartier.gid)=3
From district,quartier
Where st_intersects (district.geom,quartier.geom)
Group by district.nom It works but I don’t know how to select the line which is true. Sophie

Answer (score 4):

Probably you're looking for something like this (not sure because you haven't shown the table structures):

```
SELECT district.name, count(quartier.id)
    FROM districts, quartier
    WHERE st_intersects(districts.geom, quartier.geom)
    GROUP BY district.name
    HAVING count(quartier.id) = 3
```

i.e. grouped by the district name, count how many quartier ids there are where the geometries intersect, and provide the rows having that count = 3.